# launching firefox in silent mode

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

How is it possible to launch Firefox in silent mode from the code (without running script by dropping -b parameter) ?

Or is there any other way to minimize Firefox so that tests can run normally without disturbing user if multiple browser windows open simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
headless = Headless.new
headless.start
b = Watir::Browser.start 'www.google.com'
puts b.title
b.close
headless.destroy
```

You will have to install Xvfb.

More information: http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/

Comment: I'm on a mac. Would prefer to have it invisible / minimized to be able to see whats going on.
Any alternative?

Comment: I usually run tests inside virtual machine. You can minimize it.

Comment: Is there any way to pass '- silent' argument to firefox when opening it? The problem is a test my website with different profiles, so browser has to open with new instance each time - so it doesn't help if I minimize it.

Comment: Opening multiple browsers at the same time is a solution to a problem - what is that problem that requires you to have multiple browsers open at the same time in various profiles?

Comment: Each Firefox browser that you open with watir-webdriver will use a different profile. Minimizing is not related to that. As @DaveMcNulla said, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to avoid browser windows popping up. Is there any way to run firefox in silent mode or background with Watir?